# How to avoid nested SQL query in this case?

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery

I have an SQL question, related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284984/sql-query-without-nested-queries) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855970/avoiding-a-nested-subquery-in-sql) question (but different). Basically I want to know how I can avoid a nested query.

Let's say I have a huge table of jobs (`jobs`) executed by a company in their history. These jobs are characterized by year, month, location and the code belonging to the tool used for the job. Additionally I have a table of tools (`tools`), translating tool codes to tool descriptions and further data about the tool. Now they want a website where they can select year, month, location and tool using a dropdown box, after which the matching jobs will be displayed. I want to fill the last dropdown with only the relevant tools matching the before selection of year, month and location, so I write the following nested query:

```
SELECT c.tool_code, t.tool_description
FROM (
 SELECT DISTINCT j.tool_code
 FROM jobs AS j
 WHERE j.year = ....
        AND j.month = ....
 AND j.location = ....
) AS c
LEFT JOIN tools as t
ON c.tool_code = t.tool_code
ORDER BY c.tool_code ASC
```

I resorted to this nested query because it was much faster than performing a JOIN on the complete database and selecting from that. It got my query time down a lot. But as I have recently read that [MySQL nested queries should be avoided at all cost](http://www.selikoff.net/2008/12/10/memo-avoid-nested-queries-in-mysql-at-all-costs/), I am wondering whether I am wrong in this approach. Should I rewrite my query differently? And how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you shouldn't, your query is fine.

Just create an index on `jobs (year, month, location, tool_code)` and `tools (tool_code)` so that the `INDEX FOR GROUP-BY` can be used.

The article your provided describes the subquery predicates (`IN (SELECT ...)`), not the nested queries (`SELECT FROM (SELECT ...)`).

Even with the subqueries, the article is wrong: while `MySQL` is not able to optimize all subqueries, it deals with `IN (SELECT …)` predicates just fine.

I don't know why the author chose to put `DISTINCT` here:

```
SELECT  id, name, price
FROM    widgets
WHERE   id IN
        (
        SELECT  DISTINCT widgetId
        FROM    widgetOrders
        )
```

and why do they think this will help to improve performance, but given that `widgetID` is indexed, `MySQL` will just transform this query:

```
SELECT  id, name, price
FROM    widgets
WHERE   id IN
        (
        SELECT  widgetId
        FROM    widgetOrders
        )
```

into an `index_subquery`

Essentially, this is just like `EXISTS` clause: the inner subquery will be executed once per `widgets` row with the additional predicate added:

```
SELECT  NULL
FROM    widgetOrders
WHERE   widgetId = widgets.id
```

and stop on the first match in `widgetOrders`.

This query:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT w.id,w.name,w.price
FROM    widgets w
INNER JOIN
        widgetOrders o
ON      w.id = o.widgetId
```

will have to use `temporary` to get rid of the duplicates and will be much slower.

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid the subquery by using `GROUP BY`, but if the subquery performs better, keep it.

Why do you use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a `JOIN` to join `tools`?

Comment: Because I haven't yet set up foreign key relationships between the tables. After I do that, I can switch to a JOIN, but at the moment it is still possible to have jobs with as-of-yet-unknown tool codes being added to the database. I need these jobs to still pop up in the select.