# SQL to pull data sorted by column then sort it another way

Tags: mysql, sorting

I'm pulling the top 15 locations from the database by sorting based on the usedby column, a running total of how many records use that location. The problem is, this returns them sorted by usedby when I'd really like to sort them alphabetically by the name column. I'm thinking this might require some sort of subquery?

```
SELECT * FROM `location` ORDER BY `usedby` DESC LIMIT 0, 15
```

**Summary: Need to return the above SQL result sorted by the `name` column.**

Comment: order by `name` ? you can use order by on 2 fields if you need

Comment: @racar: That wouldn't solve the OP's problem. When ordering by 2 columns, the second column is only used as a tie breaker when values in the first column are the same.

Comment: i should have read the question more then 1 time , now its clear. Nested query have some optimization issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132905/how-to-avoid-nested-sql-query-in-this-case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you suspected, this can be done with a subquery:

```
SELECT sq.* FROM (
    SELECT loc.* FROM `location` as loc ORDER BY loc.usedby DESC LIMIT 0, 15
) as sq ORDER BY sq.name
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Gotta start getting the hang of those subqueries.