# re-sorting the output of a SELECT LIMIT query

Tags: mysql, sorting

Fellow coders, i have a table that contains a number of rows each with a date column. I would like to select the last 6 most recent rows. I can do that like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `Stats` 
  WHERE `ProjectID` = ?
  ORDER BY `StatsDate` DESC
  LIMIT 6
```

This returns the rows I need but they are returned in DESC date order. What I want is the last 6 rows in ASC date order.  How can I re-sort the output of the SELECT? Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL to pull data sorted by column then sort it another way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151077/sql-to-pull-data-sorted-by-column-then-sort-it-another-way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM `Stats` 
  WHERE `ProjectID` = ?
  ORDER BY `StatsDate` DESC
  LIMIT 6
) s
ORDER BY s.StatsDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Surround the query in an outer query and order that in a different order.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT * 
    FROM `Stats` 
    WHERE `ProjectID` = ?
    ORDER BY `StatsDate` DESC
    LIMIT 6
 ) s 
 ORDER BY `StatsDate` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
FROM `Stats` 
WHERE `ProjectID` = ?
ORDER BY `StatsDate` DESC
LIMIT 6
) as t
ORDER BY t.`StatsDate` ASC;
```